# Is rδηδ an identity on ARPs of type {p,p}?

Tags: polyhedra

### Background

In their book *Regular Complex Polytopes*, Coxeter remarks that the three regular complex polytopes are "remarkably similar" to the tetrahedron, cube and octahedron. (p. 127)

Specifically the fact that there are 3 polyhedra $A$, $B$, and $C$, where

- $A$ is self-dual
- $B$ and $C$ are dual to each other
- $C$ is the rectification of $A$
- $A$ is the halving of $B$

So for the three Platonic solids we have the following diagram:

[image]

### Observation

After reading this I noticed that this isn't the only set of 3 regular polyhedra with this property. I immediately noticed that:

- $A$ = Halved mucube
- $B$ = Mucube
- $C$ = Muoctahedron

also holds the same relationships.

And trivially $A = B = C =$ Square tiling also holds.

If you begin searching you can find plenty of examples of a more general property:

- $A$ and $D$ are dual to each other
- $B$ and $C$ are dual to each other
- $C$ is the rectification of $D$
- $A$ is the halving of $B$

In the above examples $A$ was equal to $D$.

### Question

Given an abstract regular polyhedron of type $\{p,p\}$ does $\delta\eta\delta r\{p,p\} = \{p,p\}$? In other words:

- Is the process of rectification, dual, halving, dual the identity?
- Does the following diagram commute:
  [image]
  where nodes indicate Schläfli types rather than specific polytopes.